# Todays date is 05/01/2017 but it is showing on 29/01/2017.Which method is good for me using gridview

Tags: android, android-fragments, gridview, android-gridview

[1]Here is my adapter page

```
 if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.programlist, null);
            //holder.tv=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtdate);

        }
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int dayofmonth = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        ImageView imgTv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        Toast.makeText(context, ""+month, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        imgTv.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
         if(currentFragmentMonth != -1 && month==currentFragmentMonth && year==2017) {

             if (dayofmonth == position+1 ) {
          imgTv.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                 Toast.makeText(context, "You selected at position " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }


        }



        return convertView;
    }

    public void setCurrentFragmentMonth(int month)
    {
        this.currentFragmentMonth = month;
    }

}
```

Here is my month code

```
    Context context;
    ArrayList prgmName;
    GridView gv;
    TextView textView_date;
        int month,day,year;
    int currentFragmentMonth = -1;


    public static int [] prgmImages={R.drawable.one,R.drawable.eight,R.drawable.fifteen,R.drawable.twentytwo,R.drawable.twentynine,R.drawable.two ,R.drawable.nine,R.drawable.sixteen,R.drawable.twentythree,R.drawable.thirty,R.drawable.three,R.drawable.ten,R.drawable.seventin,R.drawable.twentyfour,R.drawable.thirtyone,R.drawable.four,R.drawable.eleven,R.drawable.eighteen,R.drawable.twentyfive,R.drawable.blank,R.drawable.five,R.drawable.twelve,R.drawable.nineteen,R.drawable.twentysix,R.drawable.blank,R.drawable.six,R.drawable.thirteen,R.drawable.twenty,R.drawable.twentyseven,R.drawable.blank,R.drawable.seven,R.drawable.fourteen,R.drawable.twentyone,R.drawable.twentyeight,R.drawable.blank};



    public January_Fragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_january_, null);
        gv = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
//        textView_date= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtdate);
//        String TextView_Date=textView_date.getText().toString();
//        int Text_Date= Integer.parseInt(TextView_Date);
        CustomAdapter customAdapter=new CustomAdapter(getActivity(),prgmImages);
        customAdapter.setCurrentFragmentMonth(0);
        // gv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), prgmImages));
        gv.setAdapter(customAdapter);
```

Design [I want to show back ground color blue( border color) particular date wise but my border color not showing current position and current date.Todays date is 05/01/2017 but it is showing on 29/01/2017.Which method is good for me.Thank You][2]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vaq2Z.png)

Comment: check my forked repo here https://github.com/amorenew/Caldroid

Comment: @ amorenew   Thank you..It was nice I checked github link but  my concept is I am developing calendar app using gridview and showing particular image in adapter....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem is that you have sorted your array according to a calendar so that it will display the dates vertically but while highlighting the current date your considering position.

For e.g. current date is 5 which is at position no. 20 in your image array and at position 5 you have an image of 29 that's why it is getting highlighted.

One solution could be, you need to save the respective positions of image somewhere you can use hashmap for it. So the keys in your hashmap will be the dates of the month and value will be the image position in an array.

So your hashmap will look like

```
    +------------+------------------------+
    |    Date    | Position in img array  |
    +------------+------------------------+
    | 1          | 0                      |
    | 2          | 5                      |
    | 3          | 9                      |
    +------------+------------------------+
```

Now get today's date and compare this with hashmap keys and get the value of the position to be highlighted.

Check below code, According to your image array create hashmap.

```
public static int[] prgmImages = {R.drawable.one, R.drawable.eight, R.drawable.fifteen, R.drawable.twentytwo, R.drawable.twentynine,
                R.drawable.two, R.drawable.nine, R.drawable.sixteen, R.drawable.twentythree, R.drawable.thirty,
                R.drawable.three, R.drawable.ten, R.drawable.seventin, R.drawable.twentyfour, R.drawable.thirtyone,
                R.drawable.four, R.drawable.eleven, R.drawable.eighteen, R.drawable.twentyfive, R.drawable.blank,
                R.drawable.five, R.drawable.twelve, R.drawable.nineteen, R.drawable.twentysix, R.drawable.blank,
                R.drawable.six, R.drawable.thirteen, R.drawable.twenty, R.drawable.twentyseven, R.drawable.blank,
                R.drawable.seven, R.drawable.fourteen, R.drawable.twentyone, R.drawable.twentyeight, R.drawable.blank};

    HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();//Hashmap<DatesInMonth,ImagePositionInArray>
    map.put(1, 0);
    map.put(2, 5);
    map.put(3, 10);
    map.put(4, 15);
    map.put(5, 20);
    map.put(6, 25);
    map.put(7, 30);
    map.put(8, 1);
    map.put(9, 6);
    map.put(10, 11);
    map.put(11, 16);
    map.put(12, 21);
    map.put(13, 26);
    map.put(14, 31);
    map.put(15, 2);
    map.put(16, 7);
    map.put(17, 12);
    map.put(18, 17);
    map.put(19, 22);
    map.put(20, 27);
    map.put(21, 32);
    map.put(22, 3);
    map.put(23, 8);
    map.put(24, 13);
    map.put(25, 18);
    map.put(26, 23);
    map.put(27, 28);
    map.put(28, 33);
    map.put(29, 4);
    map.put(30, 9);
    map.put(31, 14);

    imgTv.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
    if (currentFragmentMonth != -1 && month == currentFragmentMonth && year == 2017) {

        int mapPosition = map.get(dayofmonth);

        if (mapPosition == position) {
            imgTv.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        }

    }
```

Comment: @Pratik...Yes.ur conclusion is right according to my code.Have u any demo for hashmap which is close with my code?I am trying.Thank you

Comment: @prashant I have updated the code please check. P.S.- I have not tested it, but it should work :)

Comment: ..Ok.I will check

Comment: How to access HashMapobject in Base adapter.

Comment: happy to help @prashant